when i start my laptop GNU GRUB Version 2.12 is showing
I had divided my SSD into two units and was using Windows and Ubuntu together. Ubuntu was not opening for a while. I deleted the disk unit where Ubuntu was located from the disk manager. When I restarted my laptop, it did not open and GNU GRUB Version 1.12 started to appear on the screen. In the bios menu, two Ubuntus are seen in the boot options but the Windows boot manager option is not visible. Can you help?

Grub was set up to launch in order for you to select either Windows or Ubuntu at boot time. This is what allowed you to boot Windows after installing Ubuntu.
Alas, Grub depend upon files which where stored in the Ubuntu partition which you deleted...
Your solution, provided you did not kill the Windows partition is to find the Microsoft KB describing how to restore Microsoft Windows boot system. I can't tell you how and what you need for this knowing nothing about Microsoft products, and the answer, if I knew it will be out of scope on an Ubuntu only support forum.
